# how do i import socket.io-client in angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to import socket.io in angular2.

I have tried:

```
import io from  'socket.io-client';
```

however this is not working

Answer (score 4):

I think what you're looking for is

```
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
```

This is the equivalent to

```
var io = require('socket.io-client');
```

in node.

However since this is running in the browser you will need to use a module loader of some sort to patch the references together. Typescript will compile happy, but browser will throw runtime errors if you don't configure the module loader correctly.